# Excel not transferring data properly from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

Recently I've been working on a spreadsheet that allows users to input data on an invoice template page, and then save that information on another sheet. The invoice template looks like this:
[image: Invoice Box]

I just put in random inputs for each cell. Then the data here from B17:H37 needs to be moved to a sheet named Invoice data when the "Save" forum button is pressed by the user. The data is supposed to be inputted into D:G on the Invoice data page, but the result is as such:
[image: Invoice Data]

A:C are filled in with different values outside B17:H37 (as shown in code below), **but** only the "Name" data (column B) from the Invoice box is copied into the Invoice data sheet while "Hours", "cost", and "Total" are neglected. Here's the code I have so far (from a tutorial I found online):

```
Sub save_invoice()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim i As Long
  Dim a As Long
  Dim rng_dest As Range
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'Check if invoice # is found on sheet "Invoice data"
  i = 1
  Do Until Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).Value = ""
    If Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("E7") & "-" & Range("F7").Value Then
      'Ask overwrite invoice #?
      If MsgBox("Overwrite invoice data?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
      Else
        Exit Do
      End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  i = 1
  Set rng_dest = Sheets("Invoice data").Range("D:F")
  'Delete rows if invoice # is found
  Do Until Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).Value = ""
    If Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("E7") & "-" & Range("F7").Value Then
      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
      i = 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  ' Find first empty row in columns D:G on sheet Invoice data
  Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_dest.Rows(i)) = 0
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  'Copy range B17:F37 on sheet Invoice
  Set rng = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B17:H37")
  ' Copy rows containing values to sheet Invoice data
 For a = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(a)) <> 0 Then
      rng_dest.Rows(i).Value = rng.Rows(a).Value
      'Copy Invoice number
      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("E7") & "-" & Range("F7").Value
      'Copy Date
      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("B" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B2").Value
      'Copy Project Name
      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("C7").Value
      i = i + 1
    End If
  Next a
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm still very new to VBA so I am utterly confused. I tried the debug function and this is where the code usually screws up: `For a = 1 To rng.Rows.Count If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(a)) <> 0 Then rng_dest.Rows(i).Value = rng.Rows(a).Value` . If you could help me fix this problem, I would appreciate it very much:)

Also, as a side note, is there a way to make it so rows with "0"s in the "Total"(column H) are not transferred to the Invoice data page? Thank you for your time.
[image: New Invoice page]

In this picture I want everything from row 7 and below to be deleted because I didn't input anything in the invoice page for those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the **result for loop** as follow:

```
'Copy rows containing values to sheet Invoice data
For a = 17 To 37

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Invoice").Range("B" & a & ":H" & a)) <> 0 Then

        'Copy Invoice number
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i) = Sheets("Invoice").Range("E7") & "-" & Sheets("Invoice").Range("F7")

        'Copy Date
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("B" & i) = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B2")

        'Copy Project Name
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("C" & i) = Sheets("Invoice").Range("C7")

        'Copy Name
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("D" & i) = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B" & a)

        'Copy Hours
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("E" & i) = Sheets("Invoice").Range("F" & a)

        'Copy Cost
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("F" & i) = Sheets("Invoice").Range("G" & a)

        'Copy Total
        Sheets("Invoice data").Range("G" & i) = Sheets("Invoice").Range("H" & a)

        'increase invoice data row
        i = i + 1

    End If

Next a
```

I already tested the code with your input data. It work well for me. Try This.

**Added:**

If you want to add a new condition, modify **`if`** statement as follow:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Invoice").Range("B" & a & ":G" & a)) <> 0  And Sheets("Invoice").Range("H" & a) > 0 Then
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly! If I may ask one additional question: is it possible to make it so somehow the rows with "0" in column H of the Invoice page aren't transferred to the Invoice data page? I've added another picture at the end to display what happens: basically, even though I haven't inputted anything for column B, F or G on the invoice page, it still makes entries for it on the invoice data page because there are 0s in column H of the invoice page.

Comment: I love you so much hahaha. This was giving me a huge headache for the past week or so. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad for helping you.